# Scrollbar in tkinter, for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar

I have little experience how to combine matplotlib with tkinter or pyqt.
I need a horizontal scroll bar on the matplotlib chart.
I want to zoom the graph horizontally and scroll the graph from the beginning 
to the end of the data that is loaded from the file.
After reviewing the examples, I added a scroll bar.
But she's completely unresponsive to the chart.)

And the process doesn't end when I close the window(how to remove not understood, an example taken from here [enter link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html?highlight=tkinter))

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

root = tkinter.Tk()

x = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                    index_col='DATE',
                    parse_dates=True,
                    infer_datetime_format=True)
z = x.iloc[:, 3].values
N = len(z)
ind = np.arange(N)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ind, z)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(master=root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=X)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

After adding a row

```
scrollbar["command"] = canvas.get_tk_widget().xview
```

As pointed out- MaxiMouse.
The graph scrolls, but not along the entire length.
I need the scroll to work on all the data after zooming in. I displayed this at the end of the video.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this before the `tkinter.mainloop()` call:

```
scrollbar["command"] = canvas.get_tk_widget().xview
canvas.get_tk_widget()["xscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set
```